# Why we do not initialize returned object in operator overloading method?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

I'm trying to learn operators overloading and i found code like this:

```
public static ComplexNumber operator -(ComplexNumber x) {
    ComplexNumber y;
    y.re = -x.re;
    y.im = -x.im;
    return y;
}
```

and I wonder why we do not initialize the `y` like this: `ComplexNumber y = new ComplexNumber()`.

Comment: It's probably a `struct`. Do you have the type definition?

Comment: Yea, you have right...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comments: it's probably (virtually certainly) a `struct`.

See for example [this snippet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288471(v=vs.71).aspx):

> When you create a struct object using the `New` operator, it gets created and the appropriate constructor is called. Unlike classes, structs can be instantiated without using the New operator. If you do not use `New`, the fields will remain unassigned and the object cannot be used until all the fields are initialized.

You can test this for yourself easily:

```
void Main()
{
    X x;
    x.blabla = 5;
    Console.WriteLine (x.blabla);
}

public struct X {
    public int blabla;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you have right. I didn't know we can do that. Thanks